# iOS5: willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge method is running recursive

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, basic-authentication

I am using the below code for authentication of the user with the remote server.If I am giving correct username and password, there is no issue because authentication is happening and I am getting the response from server.

But when I am giving wrong credentials,this method is called in recursive manner, so I am not able to break this.

Please help me, how to break this so that I should be able to show the authentication failed alert message.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                                             password:@"password"
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
        {

        if ([challenge previousFailureCount] > 0) {
                // do something may be alert message
            } 
        else
        {

            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                                                     password:@"password"
                                                                  persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge]; 
        }

}
```

Comment: Enter two times on "else" statement... how can it's possible?

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the error count and cancel the authentication challenge appropriately:

```
if ([challenge previousFailureCount]) {
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
} else {
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```